# Does Chrome canary share cached data with chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm having problems with testing some jsp pages.  They're getting cached by my browser.  I was wondering if I installed Chrome  Canary if I could delete all the cached files without affecting my main Chrome installation.

-Eric

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Chrome Canary use separate profiles. So cache is also separate.